# Can you keep submit=submit from showing in the URL after submitting a form?

Tags: html, forms

I have a search form

```
<form id="search" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="q" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

and when I submit it it adds `?q=&submit=submit` to the URL is there a way that I can keep it from appending `submit=submit` but still pass the `q=`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you remove the `name` attribute from your `<input type="submit" />` then that should get rid of `submit=submit` from the querystring (a quick test in Firefox / Firebug confirmed this). For example:

```
<input type="submit" value="search" />
```

Comment: Don't some old browsers need the "name" attribute to show "search" as the text of the button?  I don't have IE7 or any Netscape available to test - just something I thought I remembered.

Comment: @dave some browsers use the "name" attribute like an "id" attribute, but I've never heard of it being used for button-text

Answer (score 0):

Try using a button:

```
<button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
```

Comment: This page http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp recommends against using button tag to submit a form.

Comment: button tags in forms aren't the same cross-browser, some will use every button tag as a submit button and in others the value is wonkey not an ideal solution

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an anchor instead of a form input:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
        document.getElementById('search').submit();
    }
</script>

<form id="search" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="q" />
    <a href="javascript: submitForm();">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Or, you could add an onsubmit to the form, and use javascript to disable the input field, which should keep it from showing in the URL.

Comment: Suddenly the semantics of your form are broken, and it won't work without JavaScript. This doesn't even degrade gracefully. I wouldn't use this unless there were absolutely no other solutions; fortunately there are plenty.

Comment: 1) it works just fine    2) imo it's the best option given so far  3) your comment does nothing to help

Comment: 1) Without JS it not only fails, but breaks the entire form 2) Ian's answer is better 3) "Helping" isn't a requirement of comments

Answer (score 0):

Would using post instead of get be out of the question because that wouldn't show anything in the url.

Comment: I want the user to be able to share the link, you can't share post data.

Answer (score 0):

Change the button's name to  `name=''`

Answer (score 0):

Change the button type from:

> type="submit"

To:

> type="button"

i.e.

```
<button type="button">Login</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

No. You would need to remove the input.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect - if you put an onsubmit function on the form, you could disable the submit field via javascript, which would keep it from showing that field in the URL.

Comment: @Dave that's certainly an interesting approach! Is disabling a field enough to have it excluded from the submission?

Comment: Yes, it will keep it from being in the URL - I'm not 100% sure if "disable" is the word - but I believe it is.  I had a form with ton of search options - but it made a HUGE url even if someone just used one search option, so I did this to only utilize the ones that were changed from their defaults and keep the url string nice and clean.  Maybe overkill, but - I like shorter urls :)

Comment: @Dave I assume the question is looking for an answer outside of JavaScript, which is obviously capable of intercepting and doctoring form submissions.

Comment: @meager - while you're busy assuming, I'm busy trying to help.